How to find Fourier coefficient $a_0, a_n,b_n$ values for a sign function with output 1110110?
I need to approximate byte sequence $0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0$ with Fourier series. The function I need to approximate is a vertical step function with corresponding values of 0 or 1, when t changes from 1 to 8.
To do so I chose period $T=8$, where $t_1=0,t_2=1,...,t_8=7$. I calculate $a_n$ and $b_n$ following the formula:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}\left[\cos\left(\pi n /4\right)-\cos\left(3\pi n /4\right)+\cos\left(6\pi n /4\right)-\cos\left(7\pi n /4\right)\right]
\\b_n=\frac{1}{\pi n}\left[-\sin\left(\pi n /4\right)+\sin\left(3\pi n /4\right)-\sin\left(6\pi n /4\right)+\sin\left(7\pi n /4\right)\right]$$
Only for me the terms are a bit different, because I have a different byte sequence. Each $a_n$ term is a cosine, positive terms are those where the function changes from 0 to 1 and negative terms are the ones where the function changes from 1 to 0. So, for me the function changes values four times, so there are four terms. They change values at $T=1,4,5,7$, so for me the formula looks like this: $$a_n = \cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{4\pi n}{4}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{5\pi n}{4}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{7\pi n}{4}\right)$$. I use the same formula for $b_n$ coefficients only this time the terms are sines and the signs changes in the opposite way, so $$b_n = -\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{4}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi n}{4}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{5\pi n}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{7\pi n}{4}\right).$$ The coefficients that I get:
$$a_1 = 0.22, a_2 = -0.07, a_3=-0.12,a_4 = -0.11,a_5=-0.07,a_6=-0.02,a_7=0.013, a_8=0.023, a_9=0.01, a_10=-0.013\\
b1_=-0.023,b_2=-0.48,b_3=-0.08,b_4=\text{nearly 0}, b_5=0.05,b_6=0.16, b7=-0.032, b_8 = \text{nearly 0}, b_9=-0.03, b_{10}=-0.1$$
The c I compute following the formula $\frac{T}{2}g(t)$, where g(t) are times the function value is 1, so in this case the c is 1,25.
After computing all the coefficients, I compute the values of harmonics for each t with t going from 0 to 7 with step 0,125. This is how I compute the first value for $t=0.125, f=1/8, a_1 = 0.09, b_1=-0.23,c=1.25 n=1:$
$$h_1 = \frac{1}{2}*1.25+0.09\sin\left(2\pi *1/8*0.125*1\right)-0.23*\cos\left(2\pi*1/8*0.125*1\right)=0.41.$$ The same I do for all t.
The same procedure I do for all harmonics (the only thing that changes for each i-th harmonic is $n$ value. Then I sum them together to get 10th harmonic. The 10th harmonic looks nothing like the original function, the same goes for all the rest.
Obviously, it looks nothing like the original function, and the values go over 1 and never approach 0 where it should have. I am very new to Fourier series, and this topic really feels like totally dark area for me, so if someone can pinpoint where do I go wrong, please do so!

If you want to get an approximate analytic expression for your bit sequence, I would take a different approach. Let each box with width w be represented by the function $\sin(\omega_0 t)$. That is, when the state of the box is high the signal $\sin(\omega_0 t)$ is generated and when the state of the box is low 0 signal is generated.  The Fourier transform of a box centered at $t_0$ is,
$$
\frac{\sin(\omega_0 (t-t_0))}{\omega_0 (t-t_0)}
$$
Therefore your sequence can be represented by,
$$
\frac{\sin(\omega_0 (t-5/2))}{\omega_0 (t-5/2)} + \frac{\sin(\omega_0 (t-6))}{\omega_0 (t-6)}
$$

But, I need to approximate it using the Fourier coefficients and then computing harmonics from n=1 to 10. Can you please help me understand where did I go wrong?
